# Prolog: Sum the values ​of the leaves in the binary tree

Tags: prolog

I have a binary tree and of this binary tree I have to add the values ​​contained in the leaves, given a similar predicate:

```
sum_leafs ([Node, Left, Right], Sum).
```

I can't understand how I can do it, having to calculate the value of the leaves I should calculate the sum of the node in case both Left and Right are nil ..

```
[Node, nil, nil]
```

So I have something like:

```
sum_leafs([Node, Left, Right], Sum):-
    sum_leafs(Left, Sum_Left),
    sum_leafs(Right, Sum_Right),
    Sum is (Sum_Left + Sum_Right).
```

My attempt:

```
sum_leafs(nil, 0).
sum_leafs([Node, nil, nil], Node).
sum_leafs([_, Left, Right], Sum):-
    sum_leafs(Left, Sum_Left),
    sum_leafs(Right, Sum_Right),
    Sum is (Sum_Left + Sum_Right).
```

How can I achieve this?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have done like this:

```
sum_leafs(nil, 0).
sum_leafs([Node, nil, nil], Node).
sum_leafs([_, Left, Right], Sum):-
    sum_leafs(Left, Sum_Left),
    sum_leafs(Right, Sum_Right),
    Sum is (Sum_Left + Sum_Right).
```

Comment: Two things: The naming is a bit confusing as "Node" isn't really a node, it is the "Value" of the node. More important: This code has some unwanted "alternative solutions". If you hit a leaf (a node with two `nil` child terms), then the second clause is applicable but the third clause is _also_ applicable. This second solution always gives 0 instead of the expected "sum over leaves". To avoid that, commit to the second clause if it matches by putting a cut in the body: `sum_leafs([Value, nil, nil], Value) :- !.` Or add a guard to the third clause: `(Left\==nil;Right\==nil)`.

Answer (score 4):

A list is a poor representation for a binary tree. Let's start to change that:

- Empty tree: `nil`
- Non-empty tree: `t(Left,Value,Right)`

Using this representation, a predicate that sums the values of the leaves can be written as:

```
sum_leaves(Tree, Sum) :-
    sum_leaves(Tree, 0, Sum).

sum_leaves(nil, Sum, Sum).
sum_leaves(t(nil,Value,nil), Sum0, Sum) :-
    !,
    Sum is Sum0 + Value. 
sum_leaves(t(Left,_,Right), Sum0, Sum) :-
    sum_leaves(Left, Sum0, Sum1),
    sum_leaves(Right, Sum1, Sum).
```

But this first version is not tail-recursive. We can improve on it:

```
sum_leaves(Tree, Sum) :-
    sum_leaves(Tree, 0, Sum).

sum_leaves(nil, Sum, Sum).
sum_leaves(t(nil,Value,nil), Sum0, Sum) :-
    !,
    Sum is Sum0 + Value. 
sum_leaves(t(Left,_,Right), Sum0, Sum) :-
    sum_leaves(Left, LeftSum),
    Sum1 is Sum0 + LeftSum,
    sum_leaves(Right, Sum1, Sum).
```

Comment: Hold on Paulo. So both version are accumulating the values into `Sum0` to give `Sum`. The first version not tail recursive because we have the dual recursive descent on the left and right children (but the compiler can probably still manage to build a loop over the recursive descent along the right child). But is the second version really "more" tail-recursive than the first? After all the call `sum_leaves(Left, Sum0, Sum1)` is just hidden behind an intermediate call to `sum_leaves(Left, LeftSum)` which just ends up at `sum_leaves(Left, 0, LeftSum)`, not changing all that much?

Comment: In SWI-Prolog, we can check TCO using the predicate ```prolog_current_frame/1``` in the last clause of ```sum_leaves/3```: ```sum_leaves(t(Left,_,Right), Sum0, Sum) :- prolog_current_frame(Frame),  writeln(Frame), ...```. With this modification, the query ```?- sum_leaves(t(nil,4,t(nil,3,t(nil,2,t(nil,1,nil)))),S).``` produces 3 times the same 
frame number (= stack does not grow), but the query ```?- sum_leaves(t(t(t(t(nil,1,nil),2,nil),3,nil),4,nil),S).``` produces 3 different frame numbers (= stack does grow).